# Does a gauge-invariant Caccioppoli inequality hold?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, gauge-theory, differential-forms

(I previously [asked this question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785160/does-a-gauge-invariant-caccioppoli-inequality-hold) but got no responses after two weeks.)

Let $V \Subset U$ be domains in a Riemannian manifold $M$, and $W := U \setminus \overline V$. If $u: U \to \mathbb R$ is a harmonic function, then we have Caccioppoli's inequality
$$\int_V |du|^2 \lesssim \int_W |u|^2.$$
Possibly after adding a constant term to $u$ (changing gauge) so that $\int_U u = 0$, and applying Poincaré's inequality,
$$\int_V |du|^2 \lesssim \int_W |du|^2.$$
Now let $F$ be a real-valued $2$-form on $U$, which satisfies the Yang-Mills (or Maxwell) equations $dF = d^* F = 0$, where $d^*$ is the codifferential on $M$.
Suppose that $H^2(U, \mathbb R) = 0$, so we may choose a $1$-form $A$ (choose a gauge) such that $F = dA$ and
$$\int_V |F|^2 \lesssim \int_W |A|^2.$$
Unfortunately this inequality is not very useful because it is not gauge-invariant.
I would love to conclude the titular "gauge-invariant Caccioppoli inequality":

> Let $V \Subset U$ be Riemannian domains such that $H^2(U, \mathbb R) = 0$, and let $F$ be a real-valued $2$-form such that $dF = d^*F = 0$. Then
> $$\int_V |F|^2 \lesssim \int_W |F|^2.$$

**Does this inequality hold?**

Here are some preliminary thoughts, which are largely disjointed:

1. Physically, the gauge-invariant Caccioppoli inequality on the $1$-form $du$ has the appealing interpretation that (assuming that electric charge and magnetic field are vanishing) if the energy of the electric field cannot concentrate in a ball $B$ if it vanishes in an annulus enclosing $B$. My intuition is that this is basically "forced" upon us by Coulomb's law. What I am asking is that the same holds for the magnetic field (if the electric field and current are vanishing), but my physical intuition for magnetostatics is very hazy.
2. It seems very likely that $H^2(U, \mathbb R) = 0$ is a necessary condition, as we can see by analogy with the "electric" situation. It is known that Caccioppoli-type inequalities hold for the $q$-Laplacian uniformly in $q \in (1, 2]$ (the proof is the same as when $q = 2$; see Chapter 11 of "Maximal function methods in Sobolev spaces" for details). If $U$ is a parallel neighborhood of a closed geodesic $\gamma$ in a hyperbolic surface, then I can find a sequence of $1$-forms $F_q$ satisfying $dF_q = d^* (|F_q|^{q - 2} F_q) = 0$ which converge to $\gamma$ in the weak topology on currents of locally finite variation. (The idea of the construction is to dualize the solutions to the Neumann problem studied in Section 8 of "Analytic properties of stretch maps and geodesic laminations".) Since $F_q \rightharpoonup \gamma$, no inequality of the form
   $$\int_{B_\varepsilon(\gamma)} |F_q|^q \lesssim_\varepsilon \int_{U \setminus B_\varepsilon(\gamma)} |F_q|^q$$
   can hold uniformly in $q$.
   If $H^1(U, \mathbb R) = 0$, then we would have a contradiction since $F_q = du_q$, where $u_q$ is $q$-harmonic and hence satisfies the gauge-invariant Caccioppoli inequality
   $$\int_{B_\varepsilon(\gamma)} |du_q|^q \lesssim_\varepsilon \int_{U \setminus B_\varepsilon(\gamma)} |du_q|^q$$
   uniformly in $q \in (1, 2]$.
3. If we may assume that satisfies $H^2(W, \mathbb R) = 0$, then we can probably construct a Bogovskiı operator
   $$T: L^2(U, \Omega^2) \to W^{1, 2}(U, \Omega^1)$$
   such that for any $2$-form $f \in L^2(U, \Omega^2$): (a) if $df = 0$ then $Tf = f$, and (b) if the support of $f$ is contained in $W$, then so is the support of $Tf$. (If $W$ is star-shaped then this should follow from the usual construction of Bogovskiı operators; see for example Section 4 of "Local well-posedness of the (4 + 1)-dimensional Maxwell-Klein-Gordon equation". I guess the only obstruction to the existence of such an operator should be topological.) Writing $F$ as the sum of a $2$-form $f$ with compact support in $W$ and a $2$-form $g$ which is small in $L^2(W)$, we deduce from Caccioppoli
   $$\int_V |F|^2 \lesssim \int_W |Tf|^2 + \int_W |Tg|^2$$
   and the first term is acceptable by the boundedness of $T$; the second term can be absorbed. Unfortunately, I am mainly interested in the model case when $V, U$ are concentric balls in $\mathbb R^3$. In that case, $W$ is homotopic to $\mathbb S^2$ and no Bogovskiı operator can possibly exist (for if it did we would have $H^2(\mathbb S^2, \mathbb R) = 0$). Still, maybe someone cleverer than me can patch this argument to get around the topological nontriviality of $W$!